# Hiding views in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have code like this

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @InjectView(R.id.text)
    TextView label;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
    }

    public void hide(boolean hide) {
        label.setVisibility(hide ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

which maps to a single row in a `RecyclerView`. `R.id.text` is in fact the root view of the layout that gets inflated and passed in to the constructor here.

I'm using the default implementation of `LinearLayoutManager`.

In `bindViewHolder`, I call `hide(true)` on an instance of `MyViewHolder`, but instead of collapsing the row as expected, the row becomes invisible, maintaining its height and position in the `RecyclerView`. Has anyone else run into this issue?

How do you hide items in a RecyclerView?

Comment: Have you tried `RecyclerView.getLayoutManager().removeViewAt()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#removeViewAt(int)

Comment: you should never call those methods directly in LM. They are for LM to manage children

Comment: Hello. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272566/5670752).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no built in way to hide a child in RV but of course if its height becomes 0, it won't be visible :). I assume your root layout does have some min height (or exact height) that makes it still take space even though it is GONE.

Also, if you want to remove a view, remove it from the adapter, don't hide it. Is there a reason why you want to hide instead of remove ?

Comment: No, I actually tried to set the height to 0 for some rows. The LayoutManager does not respect row height changes. You're right though, the solution is to 'remove' the offending objects from the adapter. See my answer.

Comment: LayoutManager **does** respect item heights. 
I wonder how you are changing them. I assume you are calling view.setLayoutParams which will trigger a re-layout in the LayoutManager and it will get the new size. Something else should be wrong there

Comment: Oh you're right, I just realized I was setting the height incorrectly. Ill mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Note that if you're using a decorator (e.g. to add a divider between your items), your "invisible" items will still be decorated.

Comment: @yigit I have one reason on my case I have the first two items as constant items. So they are always the 1st and 2nd item on the list. First on the list is a controller, and the second item is an "add card". "Add card" appears when I press a button in the controller. The rest of the item are the standard representation of the list of models. I am trying to emulate the post feature in Facebook where you always have an "post what you think" card on top of the list, so I thought I could make a composite view via RecyclerView. But maybe this is just wrong way to do it

Answer (score 42):

Put method `setVisibility(boolean isVisible)` in `ViewHolder`.

You can change `itemView` params(width and height) for `LayoutManager`:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    ...

    public void setVisibility(boolean isVisible){
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)itemView.getLayoutParams();
        if (isVisible){
            param.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            param.height = 0;
            param.width = 0;
        }
        itemView.setLayoutParams(param);
    }

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
    }
}
```

and change visibility for `ItemDecoration` (Divider):

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {

            if (parent.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
                continue;

            /* draw dividers */    

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it causes lots of measurement on recycling and makes scrolling very janky.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM But if you have a lot hidden items in list, you should think about some other algorithm of displaying them. Change Layout Manager for example.

Comment: Do we need to mess with LayoutParams, wouldn't just View.GONE do the trick?

Answer (score 12):

You CAN do it!

First, you need to detect which position of item that you want to hide. You can custom getItemViewType to do it.

Next, on onCreateViewHolder, depend on the view type. You can do something like this:

```
if(viewType == TYPE_HIDE) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.empty_item, parent, false);
                vHolder = new ViewHolder(context, v, viewType, this);
                break;
        }
        return vHolder;
```

-> empty item is a layout that have nothing, (in other word, it is default layout whenever created). or code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it help!

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to set the `layout_height` to `0dp` or `wrap_content`, if you set it `match_parent` then each empty cell will take up the size of the parent view...

Answer (score 11):

Okay, so the way I did it in the end was I had my whole dataset, say, `myObjects` and I had scenarios where I would only want to show subsets of that dataset.

Since setting visibility of rows in `RecyclerView` doesn't cause the heights to collapse, and setting the heights of the rows did not appear to do anything either, what I had to do was just keep a secondary dataset called `myObjectsShown` which was nothing more than a `List<Integer>` that would index into `myObjects` to determine which objects would be displayed.

I would then intermittently update `myObjectsShown` to contain the correct indices.

Therefore,

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return myObjectsShown.size();
}
```

and

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object myObject = myObjects.get(myObjectsShown.get(position));
    // bind object to viewholder here...
}
```

Comment: This is pretty smart and simple. This should be the best answer because you really don't have to meddle with `getItemViewType` or anything else. But it does the job of dynamically hiding the child you don't want to show and also takes the height change in to consideration pretty well.

Comment: really smart answer

Answer (score 3):

For hiding view in RecyclerView I hide/show view in `OnBindViewHolder`:

```
if (item.isShown) {
    vh.FooterLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
} else {
    vh.FooterLayout.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}
```

And for example - from activity I simply redraw needed item:
`_postListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`// if you want show/hide footer - position is `amountOfPosts.size()` and also change bool variable - `amountOfPosts[amountOfPosts.size()].isShown`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, you should note that setting view visibility to GONE would not hide the margins. You need to do something like this :

```
       if(itemView.getVisibility() != GONE) itemView.setVisibility(GONE);
       RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
       layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
       itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```