# Android app crashes upon removing an item from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I created a remove function in the populateViewHolder like so:

```
viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).removeValue();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();

        return true;
    }
});
```

This code is present in: `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot).`
When I run my code and try to remove the item from the list, my app crashes. However, it does remove the item in the database itself. I think my app is not updating the `FirebaseRecycleAdapter` correctly. I tried using `notifydatasetchanged()`, which resulted in nothing. I also tried to override `onChildRemoved`. However onChildRemoved appears to not be a function inside `FirebaseRecycleAdapter`. I also tried to call the `FirebaseRecycleAdapter` itself, on which it told me it was not initialized.

Here is the logCat:

[image]

**edit**

Below this text you can find the code for the whole adapter as requested:

```
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notes, NotesViewHolder> notesRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notes, NotesViewHolder>(
            Notes.class,
            R.layout.feed_note_single_layout,
            NotesViewHolder.class,
            mNotesDatabase
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final NotesViewHolder viewHolder, Notes model, final int position) {

            final String list_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                    final String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();

                    viewHolder.setTitle(title);
                    viewHolder.setMessage(message);

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent noteIntent = new Intent(getContext(), NotesActivity.class);
                            noteIntent.putExtra("list_id", list_id);
                            noteIntent.putExtra("title", title);
                            noteIntent.putExtra("message", message);
                            startActivity(noteIntent);

                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                                            mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).removeValue();
                                            notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                                            notifyDataSetChanged();


                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                    .show();

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    };

    mFeedList.setAdapter(notesRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: post error log along with the question

Comment: What value does your `mNotesDatabase` have? Please add your code regarding `mNotesDatabase`.

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252478/how-to-remove-items-from-firebase-recyclerview

Comment: post your NotesActivity class's code where this crash is occuring i.e. at line: 201

Comment: please post the full code in `populateViewHolder`

Comment: I have provided the whole adapter

Comment: check null on `dataSnapshot` before calling `dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();`

Comment: you are getting nullpointer while getting value `title and message` inside datachange

Comment: I have added a if statement with  datasnapshot.exists(). Yet the app still crashes with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might occur because when you delete the data in `RecyclerView` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The `position` in `populateViewHolder` might refer to the deleted `position`.

Therefore, you should use `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` instead of `position`.

According to the log, the issue might also cause from `onDataChange` in `NoteActivity` please carefully check it.

Hope, it's help.

Comment: Did you change all `position` to  `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` ?
including this line 
`final String list_id = getRef(position).getKey();`

Comment: Just replaced the list_id. Yet it still crashes with the same error

Comment: to be `final String list_id = getRef(itemView.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();` ?

Comment: `final String list_id = getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();`

Comment: Then the problem might be in the `NoteActivity` please post the code of  `onDataChange` in that Activity

Comment: Thats it! the onDataChange in NotesActivity was not updated with a datasnapshot.exist(). I can now succesfully delete items from the list without crashes

Answer (score 1):

call notifyDataSetChanged() after removing the item like below

```
 mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).removeValue();

 notifyItemRemoved(position);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```