# How can I remove item in recyclerview after removing it in firestore android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How can I remove item in recycler view after removing it in my database? I manage to delete the data in database after clicking Btn2. Now I also want to delete the recycler view item on click on the same button. I have also set the get position function for my recycler view. How can I delete item on recycler view at the same time when database item deleted?

## Main Activity

```
Query query = fStore.collection("users");
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder().setInitialLoadSizeHint(10).setPageSize(3).build();
        FirestorePagingOptions<UserInfo> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<UserInfo>().setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, new SnapshotParser<UserInfo>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public UserInfo parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                        UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
                        String itemId = snapshot.getId();
                        userInfo.setItem_id(itemId);
                        return userInfo;
                    }
                }).build();

    adapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options, this);

    myRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    myRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Reset link sent to your registered E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
    Btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fStore.collection("users").document(userId).delete()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User has been deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to delete user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
    UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
    Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + userInfo.getEmail());
    Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + snapshot.getId());
    this .userId = snapshot.getId();
    this.email = userInfo.getEmail();
    this.position = position;
}
```

## Firestore Adapter

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<UserInfo, FirestoreAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<UserInfo> options, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    super(options);
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserInfo model) {
    holder.list_email.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.list_fname.setText(model.getFName());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);

    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView list_email;
    private TextView list_fname;
    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemview) {
        super(itemview);

        list_email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        list_fname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        itemview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getItem(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position);
}

}
```

## Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:id="@+id/relative">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
       />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit Password"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete Account"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your XML so I can get an idea about it Button is inactivity or in an Adapter list item?

Comment: @NensiKasundra I shared

Comment: ok please put a button in `example_item` and through the interface you can delete it in activity

Comment: @NensiKasundra my example_item contain only 1 recycler view item so u mean adding button on every recycler view item??

Comment: you have to remove single item or every item from recylerview?

Comment: @NensiKasundra I want to delete only the item I choose

Comment: every item then it's ok in the fragment but for a single item, you have to right in adapter item

Comment: @NensiKasundra I can get the position of my recycler view item when I click on them so I managed to delete the particular item in my database but I can't delete them in my recycler view

Comment: ok please add this after deleted a`dapter.getRef(position).remove()`

Comment: @NensiKasundra so u mean by adding delete button to every item in my recycler view?

Comment: then after   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: yes it's proper way to do delete

Comment: please check above first

Comment: @NensiKasundra erm I want to add it in my Btn2 on click but cannot resolve getref method. Any solution?

Comment: `public void deleteItem(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
} ` write it in adpater

Comment: then after a call from after deleted `adapter.deleteItem(position);`

Answer (score 1):

please add below changes in your code

adapter method

```
public void deleteItem(int position){  
       getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
       notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

use it by calling method

```
Btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fStore.collection("users").document(userId).delete()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User has been deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                adapter.deleteItem(position);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to delete user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

Make delete of single item though adapter using an interface in the fragment.

Comment: ok I have added the code but I get "cannot resolve method getRef". Do I need to change my adapter structure?

Comment: What is my problem actually? I keep on getting getSnapShots cannot be resolve

Comment: I thought getSnapshot is a build in function? But android keep on telling me to create a method

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252478/how-to-remove-items-from-firebase-recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you using FirebaseUI. It's an open source libraries for FireStore.

[Check this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#using-the-firestorerecycleradapter)
[And this one](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/)

With FirebaseUI, deleting items is as simple as the code below:
It also updates your view automatically at runtime.

```
ObservableSnapshotArray<ModelClass> observableSnapshotArray = getSnapshots();
DocumentReference documentReference = 
observableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(position).getReference();

documentReference.delete();
```

If you need help with the implementation, don't hesitate to ask for it :D
Happy codding!