# Recyclerview CardView remove default Spacing bewteen Items When setVisibility is GONE

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview, android-framelayout

`Recyclerview` `CardView` remove default Spacing When setting `setVisibility` is GONE to particular item

Image One When Item `setVisibility` is `INVISIBLE`

[image: When Item setVisibility is INVISIBLE]

Image Two When Item `setVisibility` is `GONE`

[image: When Item setVisibility is GONE]

**Required Output**

[image: Required final Output]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.00dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8.00dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.00dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2.00dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/cardview">

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: i dont want to remove i just need to hide the item thats my requirement

Comment: There must be something wrong, visibility = gone will/should not create that space in between

Comment: setVisibility is GONE is working fine, but there is space between items please look at image two.

Comment: Which view did you change visibility? it should be `CardView.setVisibility()`, not the inner FrameLayout

Comment: Yes are you right i do same thing only, but not workng

Comment: Have you used the same xml, if yes then where is the id assigned to cardview ? its assigned to framelayout. Change it

Comment: I know this problem. You can find  here: [hiding-views-in-recyclerview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574805/hiding-views-in-recyclerview)

Comment: sorry is my mistake now i edited the question thank you agrawal

Comment: Check your Margin buddy, It says 2dp top and 2dp Bottom so second cardview will have total 4dp margin 2dp of bottom from 1st cardview and 2dp top margin of 2nd cardview . Hope that Helps

Comment: Hi deep its not working i tried this

Answer (score 1):

Use setVisibility **gone** , use this and yes remove extra margin you have given

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="126dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8.00dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8.00dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**example**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stackone);

        final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);

        final CardView cardView1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView1);
        final CardView cardView2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView2);
        final CardView cardView3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView3);

        textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);   //visibility gone for cardview textview

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                params.setMargins(10, -5, 10, 10);//set your margin here
                cardView3.setLayoutParams(params);

                cardView3.setCardElevation(5);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Height of your hidden view to 0 i thing this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `gone` and `visible` types of viewHolder. Where `gone` viewholder has **height="0dp"**.

**BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final int TYPE_GONE = 0;
private final int TYPE_VISIBLE = 1;
private int gonePosition;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == gonePosition ? TYPE_GONE : TYPE_VISIBLE;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (viewType == TYPE_VISIBLE){
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card_visible, parent, false));
    }else {
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card_gone, parent, false));
    }
}

public void setGonePosition(int gonePosition) {
    this.gonePosition = gonePosition;
}
```

**item_card_visible.xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**item_card_gone.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**usage**

```
adapter.setGonePosition(...);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**optimization**

Remember last hidden position, and use `notifyItemChanged`

```
public void setGonePosition(int gonePosition) {
    final int oldGonePosition = this.gonePosition;
    this.gonePosition = gonePosition;

    if (oldGonePosition != -1){
        notifyItemChanged(oldGonePosition);
    }
    notifyItemChanged(gonePosition);
}
```