# How to get the visibility of the item view in the Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to get the visibility of the `Recyclerview` item in the percentage i.e. view is that much percent visible on screen while scrolling. I want to implement that if view is 50% visible i want to hide some other view else visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding views in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574805/hiding-views-in-recyclerview)

Comment: What you call `View` here? Row in RecyclerView or RecyclerView itself?

Comment: @SaravInfern I want to get visibility in percentage..i.e.integer value

Comment: @SaravInfern I think it's different, this one is asking "how much of a row in the recycler is visible at this time" and only after that he wants to hide or show certain views

Comment: You could keep track of all the underlying inflated views or viewholders in a weakhashmap, and then query their coordinates, compare that to the screen size to derive a percentage.   It's probably a lot more complicated than you want, but I'm not aware of anything simple.

Comment: @SaravInfern means the row that contains `Linear Layout`. its visibility

Comment: Try this solution it will give you percent value of each row
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168492/5498233

Comment: try this solution that will give you percent visible of each row.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168492/5498233

Answer (score 1):

Just kick off example:

```
private int getPercantageOfVisibleRow(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    int visibleRows = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() - layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    return (int) (((float) (visibleRows / layoutManager.getItemCount())) * 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this library:

https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager/tree/master/list-visibility-utils

this library gives you callback which is called when MOST(by percentage) visible item gets focus. You can easily modify example to get item in focus visibility percentage.

But just to warn you this lib is not stable and mature enoguh, am using it in production app but is very buggy and am trying to replace it with something more stable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GravitySnapHelper:
If you need snapping support to start, top, end or bottom, use GravitySnapHelper.

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'
```

Otherwise, center snapping is done with LinearSnapHelper (part of the recyclerview-v7 package).

Snapping center:

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Snapping start with GravitySnapHelper:

```
startRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(startRecyclerView);
```

Snapping top with GravitySnapHelper:

```
topRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
SnapHelper snapHelperTop = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.TOP);
snapHelperTop.attachToRecyclerView(topRecyclerView);
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/rubensousa/RecyclerViewSnap/)