# How to get RecyclerView item's parent view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my viewHolder, using holder.itemView retrieves the row's contents, so when I use setVisibility() on it, it only hides the contents of the row. How can I hide the whole row instead, by getting a reference to the row's parent view or otherwise?

Comment: `list.remove(position)` followed by `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`

Comment: That could work, but this view is directly casted at position == 0 of the recyclerView, hence it is not saved in any list. How would I be able to make it visible/add it back to the recyclerView again afterwards?

Comment: The parent view is the `RecyclerView`, you'd have to add your own parent view to do this, and then it'd just be the `itemView`

Comment: Also there are a bunch of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574805/hiding-views-in-recyclerview

Comment: @RyanMentley thank you, the last link was more than helpful, I used LayoutParams instead to set the visibility AND margin of the row I wanted to show/hide during searching!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide whole content using Viewholder's rootview.
This will hide your whole row

```
     @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext(),
                R.layout.row_select_card, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

  private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View view;

        private MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           itemview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hm okay, it is possible to check for a boolean in my ViewHolder class though (e.g. if isSearchMode then hide that single itemView, else show that single itemView)?

Comment: you can show or hide itemview in MyViewHolder class depend on your condition